# how to print the next word of a sprecific string in a line using python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to print the text in the ""

```
s="I love playing "badminton", it is a great sport."
s1 = re.search('playing (\w+)', s).groups()[0]
print (s1)
```

The above code perfectly working if the input is "I love playing badminton, it is a great sport." in this format. I am trying to print the text whatever in "". I am sure this is pretty simple, Because of the initial stage in learning python don't know where exactly I am going. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Surround the word chars with double quotes `\bplaying "(\w+)"` or use a negated character class `\bplaying "([^"]+)"` The value is in group 1.

Comment: @Thefourthbird what if I wants to include the word playing in the out put. which means it should like "playing badminton"

Comment: Then you can use 2 capturin groups `\b(playing )"(\w+)"`https://regex101.com/r/m3dHE3/1

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It is working trying the other cases as well for instance, If we consider the above staatement as example we have to print the text after playing Whether it is in     " " or not. Any Idea for that. Thanks

Comment: You could use for example `\b(playing )\W*(\w+)`  https://regex101.com/r/DFyyQF/1 or `\b(playing )"?(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/KHJU4h/1

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping (`\`) the quotes in your string `s`, that way python sees them as part of the string. Then to optionally match them in your regex you can use `?`.

```
import re

s = "I love playing \"badminton\", it is a great sport."
s1 = re.search('playing "?(\w+)"?', s).groups()[0]
print(s1)

# prints
badminton
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `playing badminton`, you can use 2 capturing groups and put the double quotes outside of the group.

Instead of indexing in `.groups()[0]`, you can also use `.group(1)`

```
\b(\w+ )"(\w+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZlMfn/1)

Example code

```
import re

s = """I love playing "badminton", it is a great sport."""
s1 = re.search(r'\b(\w+ )"(\w+)"', s)
if s1:
    print (s1.group(1) + s1.group(2))
```

Output

```
playing badminton
```

Or you might match all non word characters in between until the next word if the double quotes can be other non word chars or not present.

```
\b(playing )\W*(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFyyQF/1)